# Event ID 15 Occurring on Server 2012 & 2012 R2 VMs running on ESXi 5.5 during snapshot

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, vmware-esxi

We're seeing event ID 15 occurring on a lot of recently created Windows Server 2012 & 2012 R2 VMs that are running on ESXi 5.5. During snapshot creation (no memory snap, yes quiesce), Event ID 15 is logged on the VMs.

```
The device, \Device\Harddisk5\DR29, is not ready for access yet.
```

I am also seeing other event IDs but I've found [this KB](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2006849) which says they can be safely ignored.

Many, but not all of these servers are running SQL. VMWare Tools is fully updated and most of these VMs are also fully updated on the Windows level. This isn't occurring on any 2008 or 2008 R2 Servers, and we also have many 2012 & 2012 R2 servers that this isn't occurring on.

Can these errors be ignored? Are they benign or is there an issue? Why is the error occurring?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is this causing a problem? Is there any way to get these errors to go away? Why is the error occurring?